# Форму Авторизации и Регистрации на одной странице конфликтуют

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, formbuilder

На оной странице хочу присобачить форму Авторизации и Регистрации.
Авторизация работает а вот регистрация нет(хотя по отделенности на другой странице моя регистрация работает!

Так вот что нужно сделать чтобы 2 формы работали на одной странице нормально?

SecurityController.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function index(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{

    if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }
    //Login
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
    //endLogin

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error,
    ]);
}

public function reg_index(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    //Regist
    // 1) build the form
    $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', true, 10);

    $user = new User();
     $form = $this->createForm(RegisterForm::class, $user);



    // 2) handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()  && $this->captchaverify($request->get('g-recaptcha-response'))) {
        // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
        $user->setSalt(md5(time()));
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getUsername(), $user->getSalt());

        $user->setPassword($password);
        $role = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Role::class)->findOneBy(array('name' => "ROLE_USER"));
        $user->addUserRole($role);
        // 4) save the User!
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user->getUsername(),
            $user->getPassword(),
            'main',
            $user->getRoles()

        );

        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');

    }

    //endRegist


    return $this->render('security/register.html.twig', [
        'formR' => $form->createView(),

    ]);

}
```

А тут login.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
<div class="col-12 col-md-4" onclick="window.location='/'">
    <div id="logo" href="/">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}" alt="emr developer place" width="220">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="map">
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <div class="login-html">
                <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" checked class="tab">ВХОД</label>

                <input id="tab-2" type="radio"  {#onclick="window.location='/registration'"#}   name="tab" class="sign-up" ><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Регистрация</label>

                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="sign-in-htm">
                        <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post" id="formLogin">
                            <div class="group">
                                <label for="user" class="label">Логин</label>
                                <input type="text" class="input" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="group">
                                <label for="pass" class="label">Пароль</label>
                                <input type="password" class="input" id="password" name="_password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="group">
                                <input id="check" type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
                                <label for="check"><span class="icon"></span> Запомнить пароль</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group">
                                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Войти" form="formLogin">
                            </div>

                            {% if error %}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="hr"></div>
                            <div class="foot-lnk">
                                <a href="#forgot">Забыли пароль?</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sign-up-htm">
                     {{ render(controller(
                         'App\\Controller\\SecurityController::reg_index'))}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Мой RegisterForm

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Sudoku Laboratory
 * Date: 21.11.2018
 * Time: 4:40
 */

namespace App\Form;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegisterForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Например: emomaliev.tracex',
                    'class'=>'input'
                ),
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('email',EmailType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Например: emomaliev.tracex',
                    'class'=>'input'
                ),
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options' => array('label' => false, 'attr' => array(
                    'class'=>'input'

                )),
                'second_options' => array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class'=>'input'
                    ))));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ));
    }


    public function getBlockPrefix() {}
}
```

Comment: _а вот регистрация нет_ что именно не работает? Ошибки? Или неожиданные действия?

Comment: Ну выдает вот такую ошибку при регистрации
The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given. Но это только тогда когда эта форма находиться на одной странице с авторизайцией. А если сделать отдельную страницу для регистрации то она работает )

Comment: ну сдается мне, что у вас все поля в одной форме и у всех полей одинаковые имена

Comment: Ну нет  можете это посмотреть в моем RegisterForm.php  я его добавил. Как они могут быть одинаковы если авторизация у меня простая с использованием AuthenticationUtils.

Comment: судя по ошибке, в какой-то `массив[$_username]` приходит `$_username = NULL`. `_username` встречается у вас только в форме логина `<input ... id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />` вот и предположил, что пустой `_username` приходит с формы логина (поскольку вы регистрируетесь, а не логинитесь)

Comment: Да а что можно сделать чтобы отправлялась только форма регистрации?

Comment: Я не вижу роута для регистрации. Возможно у вас идет сабмит по одному адресу для логина. Надо сделать, чтобы формы отправлялись по разным маршрутам

Comment: Но если так сделать мне придется поместить формы на разных страницах. А я пытаюсь их поместить на одру страницу  в Табы.

Comment: Я добавлял функцию для регистрации  посмотрите в SecurityContrrolle  там функция   reg_index.

Comment: _Но если так сделать мне придется поместить формы на разных страницах_ с чего бы? В каждой форме можно указать, по какому адресу отправится submit, даже если формы на одной странице

Comment: _ там функция reg_index_ функцию я вижу, а анотации с маршрутом - нет. Непонятно, по какому адресу сабмитится